# Implement webrtc in android application

Tags: java, android, webrtc

```
package fr.pchab.AndroidRTC;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.webrtc.MediaStream;
import org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory;
import org.webrtc.VideoRenderer;

import java.util.List;

public class RTCActivity extends Activity implements WebRtcClient.RTCListener{
  private final static int VIDEO_CALL_SENT = 666;
  private VideoStreamsView vsv;
  private WebRtcClient client;
  private String mSocketAddress;
  private String callerId;


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mSocketAddress = "http://" + getResources().getString(R.string.host);
    mSocketAddress += (":"+getResources().getString(R.string.port)+"/");
    PeerConnectionFactory.initializeAndroidGlobals(this);
    // Camera display view
    Point displaySize = new Point();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);
    vsv = new VideoStreamsView(this, displaySize);
    client = new WebRtcClient(this, mSocketAddress);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String action = intent.getAction();

    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)) {
      final List<String> segments = intent.getData().getPathSegments();
      callerId = segments.get(0);
    }
  }

  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
  {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    vsv.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    vsv.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  public void onCallReady(String callId) {
    if(callerId != null) {
      try {
        answer(callerId);
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    } else {
      call(callId);
    }
  }

  public void answer(String callerId) throws JSONException {
    client.sendMessage(callerId, "init", null);
    startCam();
  }

  public void call(String callId) {
    Intent msg = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    msg.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mSocketAddress + callId);
    msg.setType("text/plain");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(msg, "Call someone :"), VIDEO_CALL_SENT);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == VIDEO_CALL_SENT) {
      startCam();
    }
  }

  public void startCam() {
    setContentView(vsv);
    // Camera settings
    client.setCamera("front", "640", "480");
    client.start("android_test", true);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStatusChanged(final String newStatus) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), newStatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public void onLocalStream(MediaStream localStream) {
    localStream.videoTracks.get(0).addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(new VideoCallbacks(vsv, 0)));
  }

  @Override
  public void onAddRemoteStream(MediaStream remoteStream, int endPoint) {
    remoteStream.videoTracks.get(0).addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(new VideoCallbacks(vsv, endPoint)));
    vsv.shouldDraw[endPoint] = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onRemoveRemoteStream(MediaStream remoteStream, int endPoint) {
    remoteStream.videoTracks.get(0).dispose();
    vsv.shouldDraw[endPoint] = false;
  }

  // Implementation detail: bridge the VideoRenderer.Callbacks interface to the
  // VideoStreamsView implementation.
  private class VideoCallbacks implements VideoRenderer.Callbacks {
    private final VideoStreamsView view;
    private final int stream;

    public VideoCallbacks(VideoStreamsView view, int stream) {
      this.view = view;
      this.stream = stream;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSize(final int width, final int height) {
      view.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          view.setSize(stream, width, height);
        }
      });
    }

    @Override
    public void renderFrame(VideoRenderer.I420Frame frame) {
      view.queueFrame(stream, frame);
    }
  }
}

I want to use webrtc in my android app.
https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC
after import project from this site video calling or voice calling or chatting is not working.
how can i use websocket library send data and receive for video or voice chatting?
can we interface WEBRTC API with webview.
or how can we do voice chatting and display view in chrom in any control of android.
now i am using webrtc in a native app but it is not working.
if u have any other code or project for webrtc in android than send me link.
```

I want to use webrtc in my android app.
    https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC
    after import project from this site video calling or voice calling or chatting is not working.
    how can i use websocket library send data and receive for video or voice chatting?
    can we interface WEBRTC API with webview.

Answer (score 1):

To get this application working you need a server-side which will do the signaling job. If you don't want to develope yourself you can install the node.js server with its desktop client from the same project (just follow How To instructions from AndroidRTC and the Install instructions from ProjectRTC):

> https://github.com/pchab/ProjectRTC

Hope it helps.

Comment: MR Albert can u give me your email or skype address.

Comment: @Link2Faisal You need to install node.js on your server and then follow the instructions from Install section.

Comment: @Link2Faisal Do you talk about node.js or which part doesn't work? Be more specific please.

Comment: now i am not connect with desktop client there is error.